# Regarding nested or multi level Filtering in Kibana Dashboard

Tags: filter, kibana, dashboard, elk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv9DD.png)We have an elastic search Kibana setup that has a dashboard. We have a bar vertically stacked chart with dashboard level filtering capabilities. Now, we are looking for multiple level filtering as follows -

1. The time range slider to update the time series dynamically as daily/weekly/yearly. While preparing the bar chart, Kibana asks for the horizontal axis time frequency to be set as daily and weekly but is there any way to make it dynamically configured by end users while visualizing??
2. Although the single level filters or more precisely the input controls are going to be deprecated soon and the new way of dashboard filters is limited to only first level.
   Example - I have some job insights for a genomic sequencing dataset and I have a filters for genetic application, sample type etc. The horizontal axis points to job submit time (time series) and the vertical axis corresponds to the count formula.
   I want to select application from the filter and then with that filter considered, I want the graph to be dynamically show the weekly based on the disease filter which is secondary filter or a nested filter.

How to achieve this filtering capability??

As far as I know from Kibana docs, Kibana doesnt support double filtering capability.